# Difference between printf("%d", 5) and printf("5")

Tags: c, printf

```
//(1)
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("%d", 5);
}

//(2)
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("5");
}
```

What are the difference between (1) code block, and (2) code block?

Comment: both of them returns an int type??

Comment: The differences are purely internal to the working of the code for `printf()` in your library implementation. The return value of either (which the code above simply discards) is an `int` of `1`.

Comment: There's no difference, as far as I can tell. I'd expect a good compiler to generate identical assembly code for them. They will be different when `1` is a variable instead. As for the return type, a function can only have exactly one return type in C.

Comment: Unrelated: get into the habit of terminating output with a newline: `printf("%d\n", 1);` (or `printf("1\n");` or even `puts("1");`) ... with the newline, the `printf()`s return `2`

Comment: Qour question is not clear to me. What exactly do you mean with "(1)'s return type"? The return type of what function are you referring to? Please [edit] your question to add this information.

Comment: The return type of what? The question is totally unclear.

Comment: You seem to think that the return value (and type) of `printf` influences the return value (and type) of `main` (which in turn becomes the exit status of the program). That's not so. The return type of `main` is always `int`, and it must be declared so. In modern (that is, probably since before you were born, but still) C a return statement from `main` is optional. If none is encountered, `main` returns -- and the program exits -- with a default value of 0, indicating *success*. That's the case in both of your examples.

Comment: To emphasize: None of the code in `main` influences its return value. The only thing that does is the presence or absence of a return statement. (You can also *exit* a program directly with an exit value at any point (not only in `main`) by calling the aptly named function [`exit()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/exit). In that case neither `exit` nor the top-level `main` return, but the caller will just receive the given exit value as if `main` had returned.)

Comment: It is somewhat confusing that the question seems to be edited such that the currently accepted answer does not address the current question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that `printf("%d", 5)` is used to print (to `stdout`) the value of a **variable of type `int`**.
Whereas `printf("5")` is used to print (to `stdout`) a **string**. To get more clear, let's modify the code slightly.

```
//(1)
#include <stdio.h>
int var = 5;
int main() {
    printf("%d", var);
}
//Output  : 5

//(2)
#include <stdio.h>
int var = 5;
int main() {
    printf("var");
}
Output : var
```

As you can see, `printf()` in (1) interprets `var` as a variable of type `int` and then prints its value.
Whereas `printf()` in (2) interprets `var` as a string and prints it as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about printf or main?  I think that you are talking about [printf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf).

> **Return value**
>
> Upon successful return, these functions return the number of characters printed (excluding the null byte used to end output to strings).
> The functions `snprintf()` and `vsnprintf()` do not write more than size bytes (including the terminating null byte (`'\0'`)). If the output was truncated due to this limit then the return value is the number of characters (excluding the terminating null byte) which would have been written to the final string if enough space had been available. Thus, a return value of size or more means that the output was truncated. (See also below under NOTES.)
>
> If an output error is encountered, a negative value is returned.

Both of those calls should return the number one.

The answer to your question is that they both return an integer.  However, you can treat an integer like a char.  [The ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/) shows you the mapping of integers to chars.

Comment: An ASCII table shows **a** mapping of integers to characters, not **the** mapping of integers to characters. The C standard does not require that C implementations use ASCII. However, the question does not indicate any interest in using integers as characters, so there is no need to mention it in an answer at all.

Comment: If the OP doesn't give us enough information.  Since they seemed to be confused that a function that returns an integer might be returning a char it seems reasonable to point out that chars can be considered integers.  The ascii table shows *THE* mapping of integers to ascii chars.

Answer (score -1):

Both the  code block will give output as 5 .
Please check the image file.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOt2P.png)

Answer (score -1):

If you have doubts, just try to use `typeof` keyword of that variable and check according to that